# What is the sense behind setting weights for the layers in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have trouble understanding weight transfer in transfer learning like tasks...

I trained two networks and saved the weights using keras with tensorflow backend (two networks are in the same model). I would like to use half of the layers from one network and half of the layers from the other network and concatenate them as a new network. Practically I want to cut two networks and join them in a new network and throw away remaining layers. Since half of the layer are top layers I couldn't do it with .pop() so I decided to transfer weights.

I tried this by setting corresponding weights from each layer (the ones that I needed) in the old model to corresponding layers in my new model like:

```
new_model.layers[i].set_weights(model.layers[i].get_weights())
```

This however loads the weights but seems to not work as I expect.

Then I tried get_layer:

```
new_model.layers[i] = model.get_layer('name').output
```

This also seems to do a meaningless weight transfer.

1. What should I transfer from my old network to the new network to carry the sense of actually taking half of the whole network?
2. Do only weights (and biases) carry all information? What else should I assign to have the theoretically same layers?
3. What does get_leyer return?
4. Does get_weight/set_weight do same thing as load_weight?

Comment: I'm not an expert on ML/NNs, but this seems to me an odd task. Transfer learning takes a network, loses later layers, and re-trains these. The benefit thus is the feature extraction learned (expensively) in the earlier layers, but then training later layers to build a classification for your very own problem. What you are doing makes to me no sense: your second network has a set of earlier layers and generated features that the later layers rely on. Just concatenating that onto a different layer set is IMHO useless. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: Yes this is an odd task. I don't want to actually do transfer learning, I want to prove one network that I trained before to solve an inverse problem from two different domain actually doesn't learn the inverse problem but only finds a mapping between two domains...

Comment: Weights and biases should be all you need. Have you tried printing the weights (biases) from your layers to see if they are indeed transferring over as you want them to?